# jQuery function loading images in a random order

Tags: jquery

I found this nice function which fades in and out content in order from image1 to image 4. However would be possible if I refresh the page to load the images randomly?

image2, image4, image,1 image3

The idea is to have a random order every time I refresh the page.

```
$(function(){
 $('.fadein p:gt(0)').hide();
 setInterval(function(){$('.fadein > :first-    child').fadeOut().next('p').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="fadein">
 <p>image1</p>
 <p>image2</p>
 <p>image3</p>
 <p>image4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no problem with this light weight plugin, [You can try this plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/shuffling-the-dom/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".fadein").shuffle();
 });
```